# Consistency strength,constructibility or high cardinals?

Tags: logic, set-theory, axioms, forcing, large-cardinals

When do we say that an assertion has a **higher** consistency strength:
when it follows from high cardinal assumptions or from $V=L$?
Both are quite strong requirements, but going to opposite directions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consistency strength is ultimately a number-theoretic measurement of a theory. How strong it is.

More specifically, assuming a theory $T$ is consistent, can we prove that a theory $T'$ is consistent as well?

For example, assuming $\sf ZF$ is consistent, we can prove that $\sf ZFC$ and $\sf ZFC\rm+V=L$ and $\sf ZFC\rm+V\neq L$ are all consistent. Therefore all these theories have the same consistency strength.

On the other hand, assuming that $\sf ZFC+\rm\kappa\text{ is measurable is consistent}$ we can prove that $\sf ZFC+\operatorname{Con}(ZFC)$ is consistent, and therefore the former is strictly stronger in terms of consistency strength.

Similarly, $\sf ZF+DC+\rm\text{Every set of reals is Lebesgue measurable}$ is equiconsistent with $\sf ZFC\rm+\text{Every }\Sigma^1_3\text{ set of reals is Lebesgue measurable}$ and with $\sf ZFC\rm+\exists\kappa\text{ inaccessible}$. All of which are strictly stronger than the consistency of just plain $\sf ZFC$.

But you're question is fundamentally backwards. We say that $T$ has a higher consistency strength when ***it implies the consistency—or even existence—of large cardinals.***  Not when it is implied by large cardinals or $V=L$.

Comment: This post is a bit old, but do you have a source on the equivalencies at the end? In particular, I am interested in how $\sf ZF+DC+\rm\text{Every set of reals is Lebesgue measurable}$ is equiconsistent with $\sf ZFC\rm+\exists\kappa\text{ inaccessible}$.

Comment: @Jade: This is the very famous paper by Shelah from 1984, "Can you take Solovay's inaccessible away?", which I believe was co-published with an expository paper by someone else, although I can't remember if that was a different publication that had this.